# Why can const pointers be reassigned?

Tags: c++

When you declare a function as const, it can only read the class member. However, in case of pointers (if the class member are pointer) then it doesn't work I still can change the class variables by dereferencing it. I have two questions:

1. In case of the function `const int* const GetXP3()const`, how does const function modify class member?
2. As `const int* const GetXP3()const`, `int* const GetXP2()`  and `const int* GetXP()` are supposed to return pointers which can't be changed, why can I change them in `main()`?

```
class Entity
{
private:
    int* X_p = nullptr;
    int* Y_p = nullptr;
public:

    // return a pointer which can be reassigned but the value its holding can't be modified.
    const int* GetXP()
    {
        return X_p;
    }
    // return a pointer which is const mean that the pointer can't be reassigned, the content or data it stores can be modified.
    int* const GetXP2()
    {

        return X_p;
    }
    // this means that we are returning a pointer that can't be modified the content of that pointer can't be modified and the function can't modify the member of the class.
    const int* const GetXP3()const
    {
        *X_p =234;  // how?
        return X_p;
    }
};
```

If the comments I wrote just above each function are right, then why can I change the return value?

As from the comments I wasn't expecting to reassign or change the pointers returned by the functions.
I don't' get any compilation error.

Here is `main()` function:

```
const int* a = GetXP();
*a = 234;  // return value is const* not supposed to change.
a = nullptr; 

int* b = GetXP2();
*b = 234; 
b = nullptr; // return pointer is const ptr not supposed to be reassigned.

const int* c = GetXP3();
*c = 32; 
c = nullptr;
```

Comment: Consider a function `const int foo()`. You can write `int x = foo();` and then change `x` because you can copy `const int` to an `int`, and then you can change that copy. This is the same thing as you are seeing with the const pointer (`int * const GetXP2()`).

Comment: `*a = 234;` shouldn't compile, are you sure you don't have `-fpermissive` flag or similar on when you invoke compiler?

Comment: The last `const` qualifier in `const int* const GetXP3()const` makes a promise that the function will not change its own member variables. And `*X_p = 234` does not do that. It doesn't change `X_p` itself, it modifies the value where it points. Which in your example is a null pointer, and so will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: `*a = 234;` and `*c = 32; ` shouldn't be compiling. Use some online compiler (like [onlinegdb](https://www.onlinegdb.com/)) to share the code where compiles. Your current code snippet anyway fails to compile since `GetXP()` are called as free functions.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen  I'm not sure I'm using MinGW compiler in VS Code with code runner extension.

Comment: Just to be clear here: `Entity::X_p` is the class member variable. You can't change `X_p` from a const member function. But you *can* change `*X_p`.

Comment: It's unclear how this would compile. Please post [MCVE]. Bonus points if you can do it on https://godbolt.org/ and then paste a link into your question.